# Deletion of node in Binary Search Tree is throwing error

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, coredump

Experts, this is my code of creation and deletion of nodes in Binary Search Tree. It's working fine for insertion, but throwing segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to delete a node (on invoking deleteNode( ) function). I don't understand what's actually the problem. 
Please help! Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int size = 0;
typedef struct mylist{
    int data;
    struct mylist *left;
    struct mylist *right;
}node;
node *root;
void create_root(node *root){
    root = NULL;
}
//Inserting nodes
node* insert(node *root, int val){
    node *ptr, *parentptr, *nodeptr;
    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr -> data = val;
    ptr -> left = NULL;
    ptr -> right = NULL;
    if(root == NULL)
    root = ptr;
    else{
        parentptr = NULL;
        nodeptr = root;
        while(nodeptr != NULL){
            parentptr=nodeptr;
            if(val < nodeptr -> data)
                nodeptr = nodeptr -> left;
            else
            nodeptr = nodeptr -> right;
        }
        if(val < parentptr -> data)
            parentptr -> left = ptr;
        else
            parentptr -> right = ptr;
    }
    return root;
}

node* minValueNode(node* root) 
{ 
    node* cur = root; 

    while (cur->left != NULL) 
        cur = cur->left; 

    return cur; 
} 

node* deleteNode(node* root, int key) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL){ 
        printf("\nValue not found\n");
    }
    if (key < root-> data)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key); 
    else if (key > root-> data) 
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key); 
    else
    { 
        if (root->left == NULL) 
        { 
            node *temp = root->right; 
            free(root);
            return temp; 
        } 
        else if (root->right == NULL) 
        { 
            node *temp = root->left; 
            free(root);
            return temp;  
        } 
        node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);  //Inorder successor
        root->data = temp->data; 
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->data); 
    }
    return root;
}

void main(){
    int option, val;
    node *ptr;
    int flag = 1;
    create_root(root);
    while(flag != 2){
        printf("\nChoose-\n1-Insert\n2-Delete\n3-Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch(option){
        case 1:{
            printf("\nEnter the value of new node\n");
            size++;
            scanf("%d", &val);
            root = insert(root, val);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            int k;
            printf("Enter the value to delete");
            scanf("%d",&k);
            root=deleteNode(root, k);
            size--;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            flag=2;
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nWrong entry\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a deference of null pointer at this line `if (key < root-> data)`, a live test of your code is available here: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/UUqrJZSlUx9LBLBW

Answer (score 1):

You must either return `NULL` in the first `if()` in `deleteNode()`, or you must put an `else` before the second `if()`

```
node* deleteNode(node* root, int key) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL){ 
        printf("\nValue not found\n");
        return NULL; // <== This was missing.
    }
    ...
}
```

or alternatively (perhaps intended?):

```
node* deleteNode(node* root, int key) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL){ 
        printf("\nValue not found\n");
    }
    else if(key < root->data)        
    ...
}
```

At the moment this falls through to the next `if(key < root->data)` even when `root` is null, which causes the segfault.

Also: Use `nullptr` if you can use C++11.